# サムネイルurl取得の正規表現について

Tags: javascript, html, 正規表現, d3.js

現在はてなブックマークのRSSからサムネイルのurlを正規表現を用いて取得しようとしています。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class = "message"></div>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

 <script>
 var imagelist = [];
 google.load("feeds","1");
 function initialize(){
   var feed =new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/hatena/b/hotentry");

   feed.setNumEntries(-1);
   feed.load(function(result){
    if(!result.error){
     for(var i=0;i < result.feed.entries.length;i++){
      var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
      var first_image = entry.content.match( /(http:){1}[\S_-]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/);
      first_image[0] = first_image[0].replace(/(\.[^.]+$)/ , "_l$1");
      imagelist.push(first_image);
     console.log(imagelist)
     }
    }
   });
  }
     google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
     console.log(imagelist[0])
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

上記が作成しているソースなのですが、このプログラムを実行しコンソールを見てみると

```
0: Array[2]
0: "https://cdn-ak.b.st-hatena.com/entryimage/273819903-1450199417_l.jpg"
1: "http:"
index: 350
input: "<blockquote title="著名ゲーム開発者の小島氏がコナミ退社　新会社設立か　　：日本経済新聞"><cite><img src="https://cdn-ak.favicon.st-hatena.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nikkei.com%2F" alt=""> <a href="http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXLZO95184030W5A211C1TI5000/">著名ゲーム開発者の小島氏がコナミ退社　新会社設立か　　：日本経済新聞</a></cite><p><a href="http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXLZO95184030W5A211C1TI5000/"><img src="https://cdn-ak.b.st-hatena.com/entryimage/273819903-1450199417.jpg" alt="著名ゲーム開発者の小島氏がコナミ退社　新会社設立か　　：日本経済新聞" title="著名ゲーム開発者の小島氏がコナミ退社　新会社設立か　　：日本経済新聞"></a></p><p>ゲームソフト「メタルギア」シリーズで知られる著名ゲームクリエーターの小島秀夫氏が、15日付でコナミデジタルエンタテインメントを退社した。新会社を設立してゲーム制作を続け、ソニー・コンピュータエンタテインメント（ＳＣＥ）のゲーム機「プレイステーション（ＰＳ）」向けなどで販売するとみられる。 　コナミ時代の部下と新会社を設立する。代表作「メタルギア」シリーズの版…</p><p><a href="http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXLZO95184030W5A211C1TI5000/"><img src="http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/image/http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXLZO95184030W5A211C1TI5000/" alt="はてなブックマーク - 著名ゲーム開発者の小島氏がコナミ退社　新会社設立か　　：日本経済新聞" title="はてなブックマーク - 著名ゲーム開発者の小島氏がコナミ退社　新会社設立か　　：日本経済新聞" border="0" style="border:none"></a> <a href="http://b.hatena.ne.jp/append?http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXLZO95184030W5A211C1TI5000/"><img src="http://b.hatena.ne.jp/images/append.gif" border="0" alt="はてなブックマークに追加" title="はてなブックマークに追加"></a></p></blockquote><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/hatena/b/hotentry/~4/y3bfYN4dQBo" height="1" width="1" alt="">"
```

といった風に必要なurlである

```
0: "https://cdn-ak.b.st-hatena.com/entryimage/273819903-1450199417_l.jpg"
```

の他に不必要な

```
1: "http:"
```

まで取得してしまいます。
こちらを除くには正規表現の部分をどのように書き換えば0:のurlのみを取得することができるのでしょうか？
お力添え宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`entry.content.match(/(http:){1}[\S_-]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/)` を `entry.content.match(/(?:http:){1}[\S_-]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/)` に変更すれば first_image[1] は消えます。正規表現界隈の用語で、前者の `()` をキャプチャ括弧、後者の `(?:)` を非キャプチャ括弧などと呼びます。拡張子部分で既に非キャプチャ括弧が使われていますね。

が、とくに気にしないで `first_image[0]` だけ参照しても良いのでは。

Comment: int32_t様
返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
おかげで必要なurlのみ引き出せるようになりました！
この改良を踏まえて思ったのですが、仮にmatchするurlがなかった場合nullを返すといった設定もできるのでしょうか？
必要なurlのみを取り出すことには成功したのですが、それによって保持しておきたい順番がmatchするものがない場合次にmatchしたものがある場合番号を詰めて格納されてしまうためずれが生じる事が発覚いたしました。

Comment: もちろん、「matchの結果がnullだった場合はimagelist.push(null)する」というコードもあり得ます。